# what are the advantages of flink vs a golang program using for loop consuming kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

when consuming kafka messages, what are the advantages of flink over a simple golang/java program using for loops to consume kafka messages?
thanks in advance~

---

I understand that flink has better support for exactly once assurance, but are there any other advantages?

Answer (score 2):

Forget processing guarantees. Flink is an ETL tool. It requires a scheduler to actually deploy any job, and has builtin libraries for SQL and connectors to external systems.

If all you care about is a lightweight binary for a Kafka-only process, then absolutely use Go, Rust, whatever. But you still need to bring-your-own scheduler (Kubernetes, perhaps?). That app won't run in Flink/YARN on its own...

BTW, Apache Beam has a Go and Java SDK, and a Flink runtime layer, so best of both?